# SOQL query returning ID's and field in to list, how do I get just the Field out of the list

Tags: apex

```
List<Program__c> programs= [Select id from Program__c Where Name='ABC'];

List<ProgramPatientAccount__c> gaAccount = [Select GA__Account__c  from ProgramPatientAccount__c 
Where GA__Program__c IN : Programs];

System.debug(gaAccount);
```

gaAccount:

> {GA_Account__c=5324561aayz,ID=aoy22077},GA_Account__c=5324561bbbz,ID=aoy22999},

Answer (score 3):

The basic ubiquitous approach is to instantiate a collection, loop through the query results, and add each field value to the collection.

```
Set<Id> gaAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (ProgramPatientAccount__c record : [SELECT ... FROM ProgramPatientAccount__c WHERE ...])
{
    gaAccountIds.add(record.GA_Account__c);
}
```

Now, if it is a lookup field, you can actually use some shorthand. You can combine two features to your benefit:

1. The Map has one non-empty constructor defined, where you pass in a `List<SObject>` and it will `.get('Id')` for each key.
2. You can alias aggregate queries, and in doing so name the lookup field grouping `Id`.

What that would look like in practice is:

```
Set<Id> gaAccountId = new Map<Id, SObject>([
    SELECT GA_Account__c Id
    FROM ProgramPatientAccount__c
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY GA_Account__c
]).keySet();
```